# Register user with facebook on firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase for my React Native app. I've successfully integrated both password login as well as Facebook login. Using password authentication, I am able to create a new user. But not with Facebook login. Can someone help me on this?

**Update:** My question is whether there is a way to signup users with Facebook. When you use Facebook login for an email which doesn't exists, it doesn't add a new registered user.

Comment: Please share your code so that we can help you.

Comment: Did you enable facebook login in your firebase dashboard?

Comment: @AndréKool: Yes I did. And I logged in also.